# Why am I getting these errors when I am trying to compile my C code?

Tags: c, struct, arguments

I am getting this error when compiling:

```
browninz.buildrooms.c:191:29: error: expected expression before â€˜structâ€™
         AddRandomConnection(struct room RoomA.outboundConnections, struct room RoomB.outboundConnections);
                             ^
browninz.buildrooms.c:191:29: error: too few arguments to function â€˜AddRandomConnectionâ€™
browninz.buildrooms.c:40:6: note: declared here
 void AddRandomConnection(struct room *RoomA, struct room *RoomB)
      ^
```

Originally I started with about 20+ errors and I have finally scaled it down to a single error within my AddRandomConnections method, I am trying to compile this code and it keeps throwing an error for this single line. I have been trying for a few hours for different methods to fix the error, but I cannot get it to go away. Can anyone help me figure out why I am getting this error? 
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
/*#include <stdbool.h>*/

typedef enum
{
    false,
    true
} bool;
// Creating the template for each of the rooms via struct
struct room
{
    int id;
    char* name;
    char* type;
    int numOutboundConnections;
    struct room* outboundConnections[5];
};




// Returns true if all rooms have 3 to 6 outbound connections, false otherwise
int IsGraphFull(struct room *structureRooms)
{
    int k = 0;
    while (k < 7){
        if (sizeof(structureRooms[k].numOutboundConnections) < 3){
            return 0;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return 1;
}
// Adds a random outbound connection between two rooms
void AddRandomConnection(struct room *RoomA, struct room *RoomB)
{
    while(true)
    {
        RoomA = GetRandomRoom(RoomA);

        if (CanAddConnectionFrom(RoomA) == true)
            break;
    }
    do
    {
        RoomB = GetRandomRoom(RoomB);
    }
    while(CanAddConnectionFrom(RoomB) == false || IsSameRoom(RoomA, RoomB) == true || ConnectionAlreadyExists(RoomA, RoomB) == true);

    ConnectRoom(RoomA, RoomB); // TODO: Add this connection to the real variables,
    ConnectRoom(RoomB, RoomA); // because this A and B will be destroyed when this function terminates
}

// Returns a random Room, does NOT validate if connection can be added
int GetRandomRoom(struct room *connections[])
{
    // Initializes random number generator
    srand(time(0));
    // Generate random room
    int x = rand() % 7;
    return x;
}

// Returns true if a connection can be added from Room x (< 6 outbound connections), false otherwise
int CanAddConnectionFrom(struct room *RoomA)
{
    if (sizeof(RoomA->numOutboundConnections) < 6)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
// Returns true if a connection from Room x and Room y already exists, false otherwise
int ConnectionAlreadyExists(struct room *RoomA, struct room *RoomB)
{
    int myConnections;
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i <= 6; i++){
        if ((RoomA->numOutboundConnections = RoomB->id)){
            myConnections = 1;
            break;
        }
        if(myConnections == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
            return 0;
            }
}
// Connects Rooms A and B together, does not check if this connection is valid
void ConnectRoom(struct room *RoomA, struct room *RoomB)
{
    RoomA->numOutboundConnections = RoomB->id;
}
// Returns true if Rooms x and y are the same Room, false otherwise
int IsSameRoom(struct room *RoomA, struct room *RoomB)
{
   if (strcmp(RoomA->name, RoomB->name) == 0){
    return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}




int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
// Room names
char Forest[] = "Forest";
char Beach[] = "Beach";
char Cliff[] = "Cliff";
char River[] = "River";
char Cave[] = "Cave";
char Mountain[] = "Mountain";
char Cabin[] = "Cabin";
char Castle[] = "Castle";
char Fountain[] = "Fountain";
char Homeria[] = "Homeria";
// Initializing a room array variable to store contents of all room names
char* roomName[] = {Forest, Beach, Cliff, River, Cave, Mountain, Cabin, Castle, Fountain, Homeria};
// Creating the structs of 7 rooms each labeled with a name and type slot

    struct room Room1;
    Room1.id = 1;
    Room1.name = calloc(16, sizeof(char));
    Room1.type = calloc(16, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(Room1.type, "START_ROOM");

    struct room Room2;
    Room2.id = 2;
    Room2.name = calloc(16, sizeof(char));
    Room2.type = calloc(16, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(Room2.type, "MID_ROOM");

    struct room Room3;
    Room3.id = 3;
    Room3.name = calloc(16, sizeof(char));
    Room3.type = calloc(16, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(Room3.type, "MID_ROOM");

    struct room Room4;
    Room4.id = 4;
    Room4.name = calloc(16, sizeof(char));
    Room4.type = calloc(16, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(Room4.type, "MID_ROOM");

    struct room Room5;
    Room5.id = 5;
    Room5.name = calloc(16, sizeof(char));
    Room5.type = calloc(16, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(Room5.type, "MID_ROOM");

    struct room Room6;
    Room6.id = 6;
    Room6.name = calloc(16, sizeof(char));
    Room6.type = calloc(16, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(Room6.type, "MID_ROOM");

    struct room Room7;
    Room7.id = 10;
    Room7.name = calloc(16, sizeof(char));
    Room7.type = calloc(16, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(Room7.type, "END_ROOM");

// Randomizing the room names to append to a random room #
    srand(time(0));
    struct room structureRooms[7] = {Room1, Room2, Room3, Room4, Room5, Room6, Room7};
    int i = 0;
    int array1[] = {0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    // Loop for each of the rooms which checks to see if a name is available, if so, apply to random room
    while ( i < 7 ){
        int randNum = rand() % 10;
        if (array1[randNum] == 0){
            array1[randNum] = 1;
            strcpy(structureRooms[i].name, roomName[randNum]);
            i++;
        }
    }
     // Create all connections in the graph
    while (IsGraphFull(structureRooms) == false)
    {
        AddRandomConnection(struct room RoomA.outboundConnections, struct room RoomB.outboundConnections);
    }
    // Assigning char limits
    char dirname[100];
    char dir0[100];
    char dir1[100];
    char dir2[100];
    char dir3[100];
    char dir4[100];
    char dir5[100];
    char dir6[100];


    // Generate the "rooms" directory name with the PID
    sprintf(dirname, "./browninz.rooms%d", getpid());

    // Generate the room names concatenated with the directory name
    sprintf(dir0, "%s/Room1", dirname);
    sprintf(dir1, "%s/Room2", dirname);
    sprintf(dir2, "%s/Room3", dirname);
    sprintf(dir3, "%s/Room4", dirname);
    sprintf(dir4, "%s/Room5", dirname);
    sprintf(dir5, "%s/Room6", dirname);
    sprintf(dir6, "%s/Room7", dirname);

    // Create a new directory that the "rooms" files will be stored in
    mkdir(dirname, 0770);

    // Pointer files of each of the rooms
    FILE *myRoom1;
    FILE *myRoom2;
    FILE *myRoom3;
    FILE *myRoom4;
    FILE *myRoom5;
    FILE *myRoom6;
    FILE *myRoom7;
    // Now opening the room files / directories to create or write them in the folder.
    myRoom1 = fopen(dir0, "w+");
    myRoom2 = fopen(dir1, "w+");
    myRoom3 = fopen(dir2, "w+");
    myRoom4 = fopen(dir3, "w+");
    myRoom5 = fopen(dir4, "w+");
    myRoom6 = fopen(dir5, "w+");
    myRoom7 = fopen(dir6, "w+");
    // Creating a pointer array of all of the room pointers
    FILE *myRooms[7] = {myRoom1, myRoom2, myRoom3, myRoom4, myRoom5, myRoom6, myRoom7};
    // Printing room file name, type, and connections and iterates for each room
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < 7) {
        fprintf(myRooms[counter], "ROOM NAME: %s\n", structureRooms[counter].name);
        fprintf(myRooms[counter], "ROOM TYPE: %s\n", structureRooms[counter].type);
       // fprintf(myRooms[counter], "CONNECTION 1: %s\n", structureRooms[counter].outboundConnections[counter]);
       // test to see if connection works
        fprintf(myRooms[counter], "CONNECTION 1: %s\n", structureRooms[counter].name);
        counter++;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem with it? Give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: When you are calling AddRandomConnection() you no longer need to specify the type. I think this function could just have the same signature as IsGraphFull(). Try calling it with AddRandomConnection(structureRooms, structureRooms)

Answer (score 1):

In your call below, remove the "struct room".  You've already declared the type in the function declaration.

```
// Create all connections in the graph
while (IsGraphFull(structureRooms) == false)
{
    AddRandomConnection(struct room RoomA.outboundConnections, struct room RoomB.outboundConnections);
}
```

So that it is just `AddRandommConnection(RoomA.outboundConnections, Roomb.outboundConnections);`